# DAO design and data structure

Tags: java, database, dao

In my java application I want to implement layer of abstraction for database operations. I don't want to bind my application to any sort of databases (the implementation can be arbitrary: SQL, XML, document-based, a bunch of ugly text files, etc)

There are many relations between entities, most of the time, the relation is 1-to-many.

**Update and disclaimer: though examples are simple, they are just a part of the whole more complicated model, which have real chances not to fit in ORM/SQL model (both because of the large amounts of data: ~several billion of records when normalized into relations and because of varying nature of data). Here I'm asking about implementing simple relations, but this doesn't really mean they constitute the only problem of application.**

A simplified example is following:

```
public class Vehicle {
    String mark;
    String model;
    String registrationId;
}

public class Depot {
    String name;
    String address;
}
```

Each of these entities has its own DAO interface:

```
public interface VehicleDAO {
    List<Vehicle> getVehicles();
    Vehicle getVehicleByRegistrationId(String registrationId);
}

public interface DepotDAO {
    List<Depot> getDepots();
    Depot getDepotByName(String name);
}
```

These DAOs are simplified as well, just to show some methods that are isolated for particular entity (to get vehicle by its registration id I don't need to know anything about other entitites).

And now the interesting part comes.
Relation between Depot and Vehicle is 1-to-many. So I have to implement this relations both in my entity classes and in DAO methods.

Right now I have two approaches for this:

- place `List<Vehicle>` property inside `Depot` class and populate it whenever I fetch `Depot` instance (with possible lazy fetch improvements). This way DAO interfaces are not changed.
- introduce special identifiers for `Depot` and `Vehicle`, so that the entity classes get additional integer properties `int id;` and we add a method to DAO `List<Vehicle> getVehiclesForDepot(int depotId)`. This approach can be enhanced by introducing special classes for identifiers instead of plain integers.

Maybe there are other approaches? What is the best way to model relations between entities and design DAO interfaces to keep database abstraction easy to use and not bound to any type of database? I'm not necessarily asking about complete and exact solutions, but rather about some principles when solving problems mentioned above.

Comment: This is called reinventing the wheel - use an ORM like Hibernate.

Comment: @PetarMinchev using ORM violates one of the requirement not to be bound to any type of database

Comment: Then use ORM only for the database part. And also I haven't still seen in a real project the data storage to be changed from a database into a `xml` for example.

Comment: It's hard to see why you want to abstract any type of data source. Are you going to change the `Depot` data source from XML to relational "on-the-fly" ? Your example seems only applicable for a relational data model (e.g. SQL). I don't see easily, how XML/text/documents, etc fit in. Why do you need the abstraction? You'll should explain this first, before you can expect a good answer

Comment: It took me 4 hours to become versed in iBatis.  At least have a look at that...

Comment: @LukasEder I want to have abstraction because I think my data will not fit well in RDBMS.I will have to store large amounts of operational parameters coming from different vehicles. And I consider this to be a dirty-type problem - I can't be sure that a particular database implementation will be ok without actually implementing it.So I need abstraction from the start so that I will be able to change underlying implementation later. My examples are simple and they fit ORM/SQL,but I don't want to end up with part of the classes being persisted using ORM and part of them being persisted other way

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk thanks but the description in wikipedia says that with iBatis "the developer starts with an SQL database and iBATIS automates the creation of the Java objects". My database implementation is not fixed, in fact I can use any, so I really don't want database choice to dictate my classes structure.

Comment: @PetarMinchev is it possible to implement DAO layer with ORM? it seems to me that when using ORM, we couple database design with model. While it's not a problem for usual cases of database usage, I doubt that i will have such a case - see my comment to Lukas Eder

Comment: I think a relational database is far better suited to store large information than a `xml` file or whatever other storage.

Comment: @PetarMinchev how about Cassandra with its nice horizontal scaling suited specifically for large amounts of data? Ok, mentioning of XML was wrong decision, was just trying to show the need of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you use methods that are localised to the DAO type, it is better to define a consistent set of DAO methods to cover those functions, i.e.

```
// load object of DAO type T
<T> load(id)
// load objects of DAO type T
List<T> load(List<id>)
// load all objects of DAO type T
List<T> find()
// load multiple objects of DAO type T
List<T> find(relation)
```

etc, if you use a consistent `id` type (`long` for instance) you can define an `interface` covering your base methods.

To load relations you have a few options, which is best depends on your usage of the objects and their relations:

- make `List<T>` an attribute of the data-holder and fill it as part of `load()`

This works for small amount of relations, when the related entities do not have relations with further entities. If they do you will have to partially load them to prevent loading too much up front (lazy loading as you mentioned is a strategy.)

- make `List<T_id>` an attribute of the data-holder and fill it as part of `load()`

This works for moderate amounts of relations, used together with the `load(List<id>)` methods to access the related entities.

For large amounts of data, as you mention is the bulk of the problem you're trying to solve, you can decouple the relationships a bit further and use DAO methods like:

```
// retrieve related entity id's for this DAO T
List<id> loadIds(T)
```

to load the set of (foreign) `id`'s for entities that have a relation to the data-holder object passed as argument. Your manager / bussiness / service layer then uses that list of id's to load the next set of entities, possibly chunked by passing an offset into the id list and an amount of entities to load.

Alternatively you can decouple knowledge about the relations by adding DAO methods to fill the foreign relations in the data-holder object of another DAO type:

```
// fill entity relations for T2 to this DAO tyoe T
void fill(T2)
```

The `T::fill()` method would use getters on `T2` to get the data needed to determine the related entities (or their `id`'s) to load and one or more setters to store that information in the `T2` data-holder object.

The load methods of most of these DAO's would leave the relational data set to `null` leaving it to be loaded later. This of course means their data-holder object getters must be able to handle `null` values as part of the contract.

Comment: thanks! As for generics - from the interface point of view they can be useful, but when it comes to particular implementation, the methods will become really massive. That's because different entities have different properties. So won't the actual implementation be flooded with checks `if (T instanceof X)` ?

Comment: currently I think the second approach (using lists of id to maintain relations) is the best one. Large amounts of data are only for some small subset of entities (operational data for vehicles - for them I can use a little bit different strategy), I'd rather stick to the solution which makes the design cleaner.

Comment: @pavel_kazlou, you're right about not using generics too much. If your data model supports it use only non-generic interfaces, having only `long`, `String`, `List` and your DAO dataholder type as arguments. If the lists loaded don't change your DAO methods could return arrays if id's and data-holder objects instead of `List`s. (when you're handling massive amounts of data and memory becomes an issue.)